# Как сохранить данные после обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть код javascript, который создает пост на странице пользователя, и записывает через express в json файл. 
Как сделать, что бы созданные посты сохранялись после обновления на странице? 
Спасибо.

Comment: При заходе на страницу делать запрос на сервер и там отдавать json и возобновлять

Comment: @Horchynskyi, спасибо за ответ! А не могли бы немного подробнее рассказать? Я просто недавно express начал изучать, с помощью GET необходимо обратиться к файлу JSON, и взять оттуда имеющиеся данные?

Comment: вы используете js? или как заносите в json файл?

Comment: @Horchynsyi, у меня в index.js  есть ajax с помощью которого я отправляю данные на сервер, в файлике server.js у меня есть следущий запрос: "app.post("/sendPost", post.sendPost);", в файлике post.js у меня функция, которая через fs.readFile читает json файл, там же есть функция fs.writeFile, которая записывает, в json, то, что я написал в посте. Надеюсь, понятно описал ситуацию)

Comment: тогда отсылайте get '/userLogened' запрос когда юзер залогинится или когда страница полностью загружена(если логина нету) - далеё на сервере :
app.get('/userLogened', function(req, res) {
  res.send(fs.readFileSync(ваш json));
});
а на клиентской части  сделайте переменную и в неё запишите 
 JSON.parse(прилитевшый ответ)
я правда не знаю как на аяксе там ответы принимать, но я думаю вы должны знать(функция sucsses или что-то такое)
попробуйте вывести эту переменную в консоль что виведет

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно сохранить пост в базу данных или файл, то для этого действительно используйте POST запросы.

Если вам нужно сохранять при перезагрузке страницы ещё не отправленные данные (например, черновик поста), то сохраняйте его в браузерный [html5storage](http://htmlbook.ru/html5/storage).

Answer (score 0):

Через запрос получить то что ты записал в json и уже после отобразить на странице

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]